# How to recover data from a query made with object "ADODB.Command"?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, object, com

Based on the code below where I can retrieve the result of a query using dynamic object "ADODB.Command"?

This unit will always work with stored procedure, and the types of parameters that will be used are the input and output type.

use Delphi 7 + SQL Server Express 2012.

```pascal
unit uadolibrary;

interface

uses
  ComObj, Variants;

function ADOStart(strConexao: AnsiString): Boolean;
function ADOStop: Boolean;
function ADOConfigParams(ParamName: string; ParamType, ParamIO,
  ParamSize: integer; Val: variant; CanClear: Boolean = False): Boolean;
function ADOSetParamVal(ParamName: string; val: variant): Boolean;
function ADOGetParamVal(ParamName: string): Variant;
function ADOGetValue(_Indece: integer): Variant;
function ADOExecute(procname: string): Boolean;

const
  {Param Data Types}
  adInteger = 3;
  adSingle = 4;
  adDate = 7;
  adBoolean = 11;
  adVarBites = 16;
  adUnsignedTinyInt = 17;
  adDateTime = 135;
  advarChar = 200;

  {Param Directions}
  adParamInput = 1;
  adParamOutput = 2;
  adParamReturnValue = 4;

  {Command Types}
  adCmdText = 1;
  adCmdTable = 2;
  adCmdStoredProc = 4;
  adCmdTableDirect = 512;
  adCmdFile = 256;  

implementation

var
  ADODBConnection,
  ADORecordSet,
  ADOCommand: Variant;

function ADOStart(strConexao: AnsiString): Boolean;
begin
  try
    ADODBConnection:= CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
    ADODBConnection.ConnectionString:= strConexao;
    ADODBConnection.Open;
    ADORecordSet:= CreateOLEObject('ADODB.Recordset');
    ADOCommand:= CreateOLEObject('ADODB.Command');
    ADOCommand.ActiveConnection:= ADODBConnection;
    ADOCommand.CommandText:= 'Procedure';
    ADOCommand.CommandType:= adCmdStoredProc;
    Result:= True;
  except
    begin
      if not (VarIsEmpty(ADODBConnection)) then
      begin
        ADODBConnection.Close;
        ADODBConnection:= Unassigned;
      end;
      if not (VarIsEmpty(ADOCommand)) then
        ADOCommand:= Unassigned;
      if not (VarIsEmpty(ADORecordSet)) then
        ADORecordSet:= Unassigned;
      Result:= False;
    end;
  end;
end;

function ADOStop: Boolean;
begin
  try
    if not (VarIsEmpty(ADODBConnection)) then
      ADODBConnection.Close;
    ADODBConnection:= Unassigned;
    ADORecordSet:= Unassigned;
    ADOCommand:= Unassigned;
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOConfigParams(ParamName: string; ParamType, ParamIO,
  ParamSize: integer; Val: variant; CanClear: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  _W: integer;
  DerivedParamSize: integer;
begin
  try
    case ParamType of
      adInteger: DerivedParamSize:= 4;
      adSingle : DerivedParamSize:= 4;
      adDate   : DerivedParamSize:= 8;
      adBoolean: DerivedParamSize:= 1;
      adVarBites: DerivedParamSize:= 1;
      adUnsignedTinyInt: DerivedParamSize:= 1;
      adDateTime: DerivedParamSize:= 8;
      advarChar: DerivedParamSize:= ParamSize;
    end;

    if CanClear then
      for _W:= 0 to (ADOCommand.parameters.count) - 1 do
        ADOCommand.parameters.delete(0);

    ADOCommand.parameters.append(
      ADOCommand.createparameter(ParamName, ParamType, ParamIO,
        DerivedParamSize, Val));
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOSetParamVal(ParamName: string; val: variant): Boolean;
begin
  try
    ADOCommand.Parameters[ParamName].Value := val;
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOGetParamVal(ParamName: string): Variant;
begin
  try
    Result:= ADOCommand.Parameters[ParamName].Value;
  except
    Result:= varEmpty;
  end;
end;

function ADOExecute(procname: string): Boolean;
begin
  try
    ADOCommand.CommandText:= procname;
    ADOCommand.CommandType:= adCmdStoredProc;
    ADORecordSet:= ADOCommand.Execute;
    Result:= True;
  except
    Result:= False;
  end;
end;

function ADOGetValue(_Indece: integer): Variant;
begin
  Result:= ADORecordSet.Fields.Item[_Indece].Value; {<- I thought it was here}
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're creating your own OLE ADO when ADO is nicely wrapped inside Delphi? What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in the community.
I would like to dynamic objects, to avoid using emcapsulada classes.
Grateful for the attention.

Comment: Indeed, the code could be easily translated over to other pascal languages, such as InnoSetup. Just makes it more difficult for me to answer as I'm used to using the built-in ADO components.

Comment: Use Delphi 7 and the purpose and create my own encapsulation class.

Comment: Managed to solve the problem this in my stored procedure.
here I retrieve the data returned:

function ADOGetParamVal (ParamName: string): Variant;
begin
   try
     Result: = ADOCommand.Parameters [ParamName] .Value;
   except
     Result: = varEmpty;
   end;
end;

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question with whatever it took to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem this in my stored procedure. This function can retrieve the data returned.

`function ADOGetParamVal (ParamName: string): Variant; 
begin 
  try 
    Result:= ADOCommand.Parameters [ParamName] .Value; 
  except 
    Result:= varEmpty; 
  end; 
end;`